# Get the output of system() in C

Tags: c, xcode, unix

I would like to put the number given by `system("stat -f %g /dev/console")` in a variable (working in Xcode using C). How is this best achieved?

Comment: Are you after the return value from the stat command or the value (group id of the filesystem) that is displayed by stat command? I suspect it's the latter in which case you either need to capture and parse the outputs from the stat command or use the fstat,lstat,stat unix library functions to get the information directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather use the [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) function :

```
struct stat file_details;
stat("/dev/console", &file_details);
printf("group id : %ld\n", (long) file_details.st_gid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int variable;
variable = system("stat-f %g /dev/console");
```

Comment: -1: This just gets the command's return status, not its output

Comment: I must say, that my answer was the **exact** answer of the question asked (before it was edited, anyways). It is not my fault, if the question was not asked correctly. It was asked for the **return value** and not for the programs output.

Comment: Well the original question said "return" which is somewhat ambiguous - however at least two people were able to discern the true meaning of the question and give sensible answers, so it's evidently not that difficult to apply a little reasoning and resolve the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `popen` rather than `system` if you want to capture the output of a command. E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int id = -1;
   FILE *fp = popen("stat -f %g /dev/console", "r");

   if (fp != NULL)
   {
       fscanf(fp, "%d", &id);
       pclose(fp);
   }

   printf("id = %d\n", id);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdlib.h>

...

int return_value = system("stat-f %g /dev/console");
```

Comment: -1: This just gets the command's return status, not its output

Comment: Isn't "the number given by system(stat-f %g /dev/console)" its return status? What else is meant here? Why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: The OP wants the value returned on stdout, e.g. 501, not its return status, e.g. 0.

Comment: Yes but why downvote? The question could be interpreted in both ways if you do not know what stat does. I'd rather delete the answer.

Comment: It should be obvious that getting the return status of a call to `system` is trivial, whereas capturing stdout is less trivial and much more likely to be what the OP actually wants. BTW it's `stat -f %g /dev/console` which typically outputs e.g. `501`. The downvote is because you evidently didn't understand the question and so gave a misleading and incorrect answer.

Comment: Yes it is trivial but sometimes also trivial questions are posted on this site. Should we ignore them?

Comment: No, but common sense should tell you that the return status is almost certainly not what the OP wanted - when you read a question you really need to take into account that the OP may not have expressed it very well, and try and answer the *real* question behind it rather than just taking it literally. BTW re-read the *title* of the question.